# I have a project where I need to display a list of actors who have been in a movie with both Keanu Reeves and Nicholas Cage using React and Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, axios

The API endpoints are:

https://switch-yam-equator.azurewebsites.net/api/movies , /actors, /validation.

I also have a CORS token.

I got as far as returning the API JSON into the console and rendering it on screen. But Im stuck on how to utilize the data to get the list of specific actors. Each actor has a unqiue actorId. Nicholas Cage actorId is 115 and Keanu Reeves actorId is 206.

How can I make a list of actors who also have these same actorIds associated with them?

```
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';




function App() {
  
  
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
      axios.request({
        method: 'GET',
        baseURL:'https://switch-yam-equator.azurewebsites.net/api/movies',
        headers:'x-chmura-cors:c3ed0d1a-98f4-42e8-bff9-956b17323892',
      }).then(res => {
        console.log("Getting movie data from server", res.data)
        setData(res.data)
      }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, []);

    const array = data.filter((movie) => movie.title).sort((a,b)=> 
    (a.title > b.title)? 1: -1).map((data,index) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{data.movieId}</td>
          <td>{data.title}</td>
          <td>{data.actors}</td>
        </tr>
      );

    })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Movie Data</h1>
      <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Actor ID</th>
    <th>Movie</th>
    <th>Actors</th>
  </tr>

  {array}
</table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This question is too broad - narrow the scope of the question to something very specific and reduce the code shown to only that which is directly related to it. Note that he main benefit of completing this homework excerise is to figure it out for yourself. If you are spoon fed the answer, you won't learn nearly as much.